# jquery mobile data-lastval

Tags: jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I need help with an Intel XDK project.
After research I was succesfull to create an autocomplete form.
However, if the user do not select the value from filter list,
and enter the value manually, it is not saved to the variable.
It would be possible to select the value in "data-lastval".
Here is the code that appears in DOM. But with all the research I do, I cannot understand, how to fetch this content of data-lastval and put in into a variable. On selection of the list item it goes saved to a hidden input field and can be stored to localstorage. I need help in building this javascript or jquery mobile selector, like var xstreet = ...
"If"-logic will decide, that the hidden field was empty, and then put "xstreet" instead in this.

```
<div class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear ui-body-e ui-corner-all">
<input data-type="search" placeholder="street" data-lastval="2323">
<a href="#" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" title="Clear text">Clear text</a></div>
```

Code in src:

```
<div class="widget uib_w_15 form1widths labelwhite form1forms streetfield" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0" id="streetfield"><input type="hidden" id="xd">
          <ul class="autocomplete"  data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" 
          data-filter-placeholder="street" data-filter-theme="e"></ul>
        </div>
```

Code in the head:

```
<script>
            $('#streetfield ul').listview();
            var gcity = window.localStorage.getItem("city");

            $(document).on( "pageinit", "#form", function() {
              $(".autocomplete").on("listviewbeforefilter", function(e, data ) {        
                  var $ul=$(this);
                  var value = $( data.input ).val();
                  var dropdownContent = "" ;
                  $ul.html("") ;          
                  if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
                    var response = ['data1','data2','data3'];
$('.autocomplete').show();           
            $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading' ></span></div></li>" );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $.each(response, function( index, val ) {
            dropdownContent += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
            $ul.html( dropdownContent );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");  
                              });
                            }
                          });
                        });

            $(document).on( "click", ".autocomplete li", function() {      
                var selectedItem = $(this).html();
                $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val(selectedItem);   
                $('.autocomplete').hide();     
                    }); 


 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, nobody helped. I think, this may be the solution.
I found it in an other case.

```
var x = $(#id).attr('data-lastval')
```

maybe it can help somebody.